# UWP - HttpClient in while loop only executed GET once and returns the same string as the first executed value

Tags: c#, loops, http, get, uwp

I want to call GET method repeatedly to get random strings , as

```
while (!isFinished)
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string result = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("the consistent url"));
                    //I tried this as well
                    //var res = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("the consistent url"));
                    //string outp = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
```

It should return different strings (I'm sure) but the return values are always the same as the first execution . Then I used Fiddler to watch my network traffic , I found that there is only one GET method called and the program are still in loop and returns same value . I don't know why.

In comparison , I tried to call another API by POST method , it works well . So what's the problem?

Comment: I would guess that it is caching the result and not even making the subsequent calls.  You can try dynamically appending a bogus querystring value equal to the current ticks to fake it out.

Comment: If you look at the HTTP headers being returned with Fiddler, you'll probably find that the response to your GET is cacheable. Either get the headers fixed / changed, or follow schumi1331's advice below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the HttpClient with a `IHttpFilter` to set up cache usage:

```
HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
// Setting it to .NoCache always forces a new request
filter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior.NoCache;
filter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.Default;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(filter);
// .. your request code
```